# Inequality involving modulus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Show that
$$
\left\vert z^{3}+\frac{1}{z^{3}}\right\vert \leq1\Rightarrow\left\vert
z+\frac{1}{z}\right\vert \leq1.
$$
I have tried with the triangle inequality and the reverse triangle inequality, i.e.
$$
|a+b|\le|a|+|b| \text{ and } ||a|-|b||\le|a-b|,\forall a,b\in \mathbb{C}.
$$

Comment: Are you sure the problem is correct?   With $z = e^{i\pi/6}$, $z^3 = e^{i\pi/2} = i$, and $z^3+z^{-3} = i - i = 0 \le 1$, but $z+z^{-1} = \sqrt 3 \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little forced exercise...the original one is with $|...|\le 2\implies |...|\le 2$ (one can see Titu Andreescu, Complex numbers from A to Z...)...For this one, using the identity $$
\left(z+\dfrac{1}{z} \right)^3=z^3+\dfrac{1}{z^3}+3\left(z+\dfrac{1}{z} \right),
$$
we have $$
\left|z+\dfrac{1}{z} \right|^3\le\left|z^3+\dfrac{1}{z^3}\right|+3\left|z+\dfrac{1}{z} \right|
\le2+3\left|z+\dfrac{1}{z} \right|.
$$
Letting $0<a=\left|z+\dfrac{1}{z} \right|$, we get
$$
a^3-3a-1\le 0\Leftrightarrow (a-x_0)(a-x_1)(a-x_2)\le0,
$$ where $x_0=-1,53...,x_1=-0,34...,x_2=1,87...$ (see [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E3-3*x-1%3D0) or using Rolle theorem we get rapidly $x_2$ and so on...).
Since $(a-x_0)(a-x_1)>0$ when $a<x_0$ or $a>x_1$, it follows that
$$
a-1,87\le 0 \Leftrightarrow a\le 1,87.
$$
Finally we obteined a better estimation, a limitation and "the desired inequality". Something is rotten in the state of Denmark...